# Scala's Ordering and Nothing

Tags: scala, implicit

The Scala's `Ordered` trait is depricated, so we have to use `Ordering`. I was trying to rewrite my BST class to use `Ordering` and got a compile error. Can anyone explain me how to use `Ordering` and `Nothing` correctly. Here is my code:

```
abstract sealed class Tree[+A: Ordering] {
  def value: A
  def left: Tree[A]
  def right: Tree[A]
  def isEmpty: Boolean

 /**
  * Time - O(1)
  * Space - O(1)
  */
 def mkTree(v: A, l: Tree[A] = Leaf, r: Tree[A] = Leaf): Tree[A] = 
   Branch(v, l, r)

 /**
  * Fails with message.
  */
 def fail(s: String): Nothing =
   throw new NoSuchElementException(s)
}

case object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing] {
  def value: Nothing = fail("Empty tree.")
  def left: Tree[Nothing] = fail("Empty tree.")
  def right: Tree[Nothing] = fail("Empty tree.")
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
}

case class Branch[A: Ordering](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

When compiling I got the following:

```
Tree.scala:21: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Nothing.
case object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing] {
             ^
   one error found
```

I used to write this class as `abstract class Tree[+A <% Ordered[A]]` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is not so much with `Ordering` as with the way you've set up your tree. The error message is self-explanatory: you've said there should be an implicit ordering for the type parameter, but then in the case of `Leaf` you've given it the type parameter `Nothing`, which doesn't have an ordering.

So I would say that the requirement for every `Tree` to have an ordering is incorrect. All you'd need to do to fix that is remove `: Ordering` from your first line, since you've already included that requirement in `Branch`, where it does make sense.

Your `mkTree` method would require an `(implicit ord: Ordering[A])` parameter, but I don't see what purpose this method serves anyway - it looks like a factory method that belongs in a companion object (which it does, since you simply defer to the Branch object) - so I would remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Luigi is correct that the order does not make sense for the Tree type.  However this requirement would be more obvious and the design would be cleaner if it using an [Algebraic Data Type](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Functional%20programming-Case%20classes%20as%20algebraic%20data%20types).  These use the class hierarchy as part of interface, as a result they are more functional than object oriented (like Option and List in Scala).

Then you use the case classes directly to instantiate them (no need for the mkTree function), and pattern matching to retrieve them.

For Example:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
}

case object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
}

case class Branch[+A: Ordering](value: A, left: Tree[A] = Leaf, right: Tree[A] = Leaf) extends Tree[A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}

def depthFirstSearch[A: Ordering](tree: Tree[A], expected: A): Option[Branch[A]] = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._

  tree match {
    case t @ Branch(value, _, _) if value == expected => Some(t)
    case Branch(value, left, _) if value > expected => depthFirstSearch(left, expected)
    case Branch(value, _, right) if value < expected => depthFirstSearch(right, expected)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree that `value`, `left` and `right` don't need to be in the `Tree` trait. I reckon OP is following the implementation of `List` as detailed in chapter 22 of Programming In Scala. `head` and `tail` are defined in `List` rather than only in `::`. Not sure why but I suspect it's legacy from functional languages with weaker type systems.